# How to change the material-ui-pickers time-picker timezone using date-fns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

import { format } from 'date-fns-tz'; import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns"; export default class DateFnsTzUtils extends DateFnsUtils { constructor(props) { super(); this.timeZone = props.timeZone; } format(date, formatString) { return format(date, formatString, { timeZone: this.timeZone, locale: this.locale }); } }

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle. For me, I was trying to have my date time picker format to a specific zone. The documentation page at https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/formats had the information I needed.

From the link above:

```
import format from "date-fns/format";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import frLocale from "date-fns/locale/fr";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import { DatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";

class LocalizedUtils extends DateFnsUtils {
  getDatePickerHeaderText(date) {
    return format(date, "d MMM yyyy", { locale: this.locale });
  }
}

function DateFnsLocalizationExample() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={LocalizedUtils} locale={frLocale}>
      <DatePicker
        clearable
        helperText="Localization done right"
        format="d MMM yyyy"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        clearLabel="vider"
        cancelLabel="annuler"
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

export default DateFnsLocalizationExample;
```